# Is the expression "while the temperature is less than.. " incorrect?

Tags: conjunctions

> The air conditioner works while/when the room temperature is less than 10℃.

I would like to know whether using the word "while" in the above sentence I created is incorrect.

I googled the expression "while the temperature is less than" and found only two results, and then googled the expression "when the temperature is less than" and found a great number of results.

Comment: Either word will serve, and neither is incorrect. In general, "googling" is an unreliable method of determining whether a given usage is "correct", because the sample of web pages includes only those which have been indexed by the Google crawler, and because web pages themselves are often created by authors with a minimal interest in "correct" English, or by non-native speakers. The most a Google search can determine with certainty is whether a given usage is employed at all.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=when+it+is+less+than%2C+while+it+is+less+than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhen%20it%20is%20less%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhile%20it%20is%20less%20than%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of

> while
>
> We can play outside **while** the sun is shining.

is correct to mean "*the period of time during which*".

However, your sentence itself my be viewed as *incorrect* since the purpose of an air conditioner is to *lower* the ambient temperature, the expression would usually be

> The air conditioner works **while** the room temperature is **above**...
>   The air conditioner works **when** the room temperature is **above**...

Comment: Unless, of course, there is more to the story, such as: _The air conditioner works while the [outside] temperature is below ten degrees. Once the temperature gets higher than ten, though, it has to work too hard to keep the room cool, and it usually quits working after an hour or so._

Comment: I agree that my example is strange...